# What is considered "best practice" to test semantic race conditions in akka?

Tags: testing, concurrency, akka, actor, race-condition

Consider the following actor:

```
class Stateful(worker: ActorRef) extends Actor {
   val queue = // immutable queue with details
   def receive = {
      case NewJob(details) => worker ! details
      case JobRejection(details) if sender == worker => // enqueue
      case JobRequest if sender == worker => // dequeue and send to worker
   }
}
```

This simple actor forwards all the jobs to its underlying worker. If the worker is too busy he rejects the job and the job gets enqueued for later. At some point the worker is done and requests another job from the queue and so on.

In order to test this actor I'm passing a fake worker which rejects the first job, so I can test if it is actually in the queue (there is a `GetJobs` message for this and the queue is immutable so no worries). After having the job rejected I `scheduleOnce` to send the `JobRequest` with a `delay` of `100 millis`.

Now I send the job from my test suite, wait a little using the `scheduleOnce` technique and send the GetJobs message. If I'm lucky the job is in the queue. I repeat the procedure and this time the queue should be empty again. And sometimes it is.

Is there a better way to control the timing? Because essentially there are three delays, which I manually have to tune. And there are no guaranties that this tuning is going to work on a different machine or even on mine after adding another couple of such tests.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a fake worker use a [TestProbe](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.5/akka/testkit/TestProbe.html).  Then you can use the standard TestKit methods on the probe and have the probe send messages back the the `Stateful` actor.

See the [section on using Probes](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.5/scala/testing.html#Using_Multiple_Probe_Actors) in the reference manual.